# Reset textbox text via timer and focus on it again, in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using onclick for reset and focus for a textbox text in Javasript. 
i want to eliminate this process and implement timer of 1.5sec.. so the textbox text will automatically goes off and there is again a focus on it.

```
function refresh()
  {
  var resetbutton = document.getElementById("myText");
  resetbutton.value="";
  resetbutton.focus();
  }
```

Comment: every 1.5seconds you want it to focus and every 1.5 you want it to unfocus ?

Comment: for every 1.5sec, the text should be wiped off and focus in immediately.

Comment: so you need an input ? where you write something in it, but after 1.5 it resets to "" , thats all ?   then after 1.5s you need the old value of input ?

Comment: i dont need an old value again.  just after 1.5sec, it has to be cleared and be ready for next input..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for a setInterval. Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Example</p>
<input id="myText" type="text" name="fname" value="delete this">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {

  var asd = setInterval(refresh, 1500);

  function refresh()
  {
    var resetbutton = document.getElementById("myText");
    resetbutton.value="";
    resetbutton.focus();
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() and then clear the value and re-focus on the textarea. Below you can see an example on mouse out event.

```
    <script>
            const resetbutton = document.getElementById("myText");

            resetbutton.onmouseout = function() {
                //1 second delay
                let delay = 1500;
                setTimeout(function() {
                //clear value and re-focus
                resetbutton.value="";
                resetbutton.focus();
                }, delay);
            };
      </script>
```